# Carbon::parse -> set default to UK format

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

My user enters data in a form in order to search on dates.  The format of the string I receive can be as per the following examples: `tomorrow`, `next week`, `last year` or `01/03/2017`.  As you notice, by design, the input field is intended to be as flexible as possible for the user.

So anyway, the problem is that some of my users are British.  Therefore, when they enter `1/3/2017` they intend to mean 1st March 2017.  However, the following code:

```
Carbon::parse ($input);
```

interprets the date as 3rd Jan 2017.  Before you waste your time and mine by suggesting work-arounds like `Carbon::createFromFormat()`, note the bit above where I note that flexibility is a key part of the functionality here.

I think what I'll probably end up doing is extending the `Carbon{}` class and `parse()` function, then swap the string with some regexp so that `1/3/2017` becomes `3/1/2017` before being processed by Carbon.

Nevertheless, perhaps some clever bod out there knows a better way of making Carbon sensitive to language/territory/region?

Many thanks!

Comment: Send a utc format string from client

Comment: @AbhishekPatel Could you explain how that would be done?

Comment: depends on the client, assuming a web front end, js has a method to convert date objects to utc strings, it is called `.toIsoString()` if I remember correctly. You might also want to look at `moment.js` if dealing a lot with date and time

Comment: @AbhishekPatel It delves slightly further into a different technology than I really intended to go.  But it's not a silly answer.  I will look it up, thanks.

Comment: I see, another simple solution will be to send Unix time epochs to server, the idea is to always send a consistent format to server, or somehow notify it of what time zone the user is from. But I'd say sending a consistent format is easier and simpler.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel I think I'd agree with you there :-)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I agree with @AbhishekPatel, make the server strict on what format it accepts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you know where to look!!
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Apparently the following is true:

```
$american = Carbon::parse ('1/3/2017'); // Jan 3, 2017
$european = Carbon::parse ('1-3-2017'); // 1 March, 2017
```

So changing slashes to dashes (or dashes to slashes) was the answer I was after!

Answer (score 1):

As you alluded to, what about making a replacement Carbon class by doing something like this?

In **config/app.php**

```
<?php

'aliases' => [
    // all of the aliases
    'Carbon' => App\Carbon::class,
],
```

And then create this class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon as BaseCarbon;

class Carbon
{
    public static function parse($time = null, $tz = null)
    {
        try {
            return BaseCarbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $time, $tz);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // This will allow you to catch on when you pass a string like "tomorrow"
            return BaseCarbon::parse($time, $tz);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do `Carbon::parse('2-3-2010');` and have it be seen as 2nd of March, 2010 or `Carbon::parse('tomorrow');` and have it be tomorrow.

You could figure out other ways to construct this so that the format can be specific based on user locale or something.

Comment: Yes.  I understand exactly what you're saying, and you're thinking in exactly the same direction as I have been.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is a code snippet that I came up with, it will accept Carbon valid strings like "tomorrow", etc. or Unix Time epochs.

```
$dt = is_numeric($userDate)? Carbon::createFromTimestamp((float)$userDate) 
                        : new Carbon($userDate);
```

The idea is to always send a consistent format to server and do all the conversions at the client side before sending them to the server. Each language platform has tools to convert time from locale to unix epochs so that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Having thought about this a while, I don't really see how shifting the work from the server to the client helps very much.  You still have to do the calculations - it's just that you happen to do it somewhere else.  Nevertheless, it's not a bad idea to receive unix-timestamps as a possible form of input.  However, I can't accept this as an answer, because it doesn't really answer the original main question.